# Problems with CLIPS and JAVA

Tags: java, expert-system, clips

I'm creating an expert system in CLIPS, The user will use the system interfacing through GUI in Java. Obviously, I use the library CLIPSJNI.

My expert system involves planning scuba diving (I'm creating for academic purposes, I love SCUBA, and so...).

To begin with, I have relied on the AutoDemo example
( https://sourceforge.net/p/clipsrules/code/HEAD/tree/clipsjni/examples/ )

Now, my project is still at the beginning, but already has a bugs.

You can try my project and notice the bug: if I do a choice and I press NEXT ("Successivo", I'm italian), and after I go back to some screen (with "Precedente") and change my choice to another... the system does not display the correct next screen! 
I believe that the problem is in scuba.clp, in "GUI INTERACTION RULES" (but I'm not 100% sure).

EDIT: 
I've uploaded my project here:
https://github.com/gioce90/SCUBA_Diving_ExpertSystem
Please look that. I've solved more much, but I have others problems...
Please look SmartPlan.Java and scuba.clp